# Многопоточность в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть следующий код

```
public class MyWindow: Window
{
    private delegate void SomeDelegate();

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        SomeControl.DoAnything();
    }

    private void SomeMethodAsync()
    {
        var d = new SomeDelegate(SomeMethod);
        d.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Само собой я не могу получить доступ к контролу из другого потока. Поэтому

```
SomeControl.DoAnything();
```

нужно обернуть в

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { SomeControl.DoAnything(); }));
```

Но это избыточно, если я вызываю `SomeMethod()` напрямую. Как в этом случае лучше поступить?

Comment: Используете какой-нибудь MVVM фреймворк?

Comment: @ixSci, не использую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое, это сделать так:

```
if(Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    SomeControl.DoAnything(); 
else 
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => SomeControl.DoAnything(););
```

Но это решение невозможно тестировать в юнит тестах, поэтому, лучшим решением будет запоминание UI Dispatcher во ViewModel, и дальнейшее использование этого запомненного аргумента, вместо глобального обращения к `Application`. Если используете какой-нибудь MVVM фреймворк, там наверняка эта функциональность есть из коробки.

Comment: Учитывая, что тут явно метод самой вьюшки - может использовать диспетчер самой вьюхи? `SomeControl.Dispatcher` всмысле. Или в тестах это всё равно не вариант? =)

Comment: @Monk, я, скорее, отвечаю на вопрос в общем виде, так он будет более полезен. Если говорить конкретно по коду из вопроса, то если кто-то вызывает метод окна из не-UI потока, то это уже «попахивает», причём сильно.

Comment: @ixSci, чем там, говорите, этот код попахивает? :) Расскажите подробно, пожалуйста. Ответ на вопрос "Как в этом случае лучше поступить", вполне может начинаться со строк "удалите нафиг свой код и пишите вот это" :) Поэтому, пожалуйста, дополните ответ и напишите, как вы работаете с потоками.

Comment: @iRumba, здесь дело не в потоках, а в том, что, судя по всему, у Вас во View пробралась какая-то логика, которая там быть не должна. Классическое GUI приложение должно подчиняться простой модели: Модель-Посредник-Представление, для WPF это MVVM, расписывать всё это подробно я не буду, об этом люди громадные статьи и книги пишут. К тому же — один вопрос, один ответ. Вы задали вполне конкретный вопрос, на который я дал вполне конкретный ответ. Если У Вас есть вопрос по дизайну, то задавайте его отдельно, пожалуйста.

Comment: И да. Код не просто попахивает, код реально воняет. код написан не мной. Я лишь кое что в нем меняю. В нем даже намека на MVVM нет, но если подводить код под этот паттерн, уйдет куча времени. Это не входит в мою задачу, так что... Оперирую тем, что имею

Comment: Да, тут вся логика во вью находится...

Comment: @iRumba, Вы можете потихоньку улучшать приложение, перенося логику в отдельные классы. А можете плюнуть и просто исправлять проблемы, по мере их поступления — это зависит от Вашего интереса к проекту.